# Show that there exists a tree with vertex set $\{ x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ so that $\deg(x_i)=d_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, trees

> Given a sequence $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$ be a sequence of positive integers with $\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} d_i = 2n-2$. Show that there exists a tree with vertex set $\{ x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ so that $\deg(x_i)=d_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

My attempt:

Suppose there exists a tree $T$ with vertex set $\{x_1,..., x_n\}$ (i.e. $|V(T)|=n$) and let $d_1,..., d_n$ be a sequence of positive integers with $\sum ^{n}_{i=1} d_i = 2n-2$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{x \in V(T)} \text{deg}(x_i) &= 2|E(T)|\\ \tag{Since $T$ is a tree}
&= 2(|V(T) -1|)\\ 
&= 2(n-1)\\
\end{align}

Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_{x \in V(T)} \text{deg}(x_i) = 2n-2 = \sum ^{n}_{i=1} d_i$ where deg$(x_i)=d_i$ as required.

> **Question:**
>
> Is this proof valid? Am I allowed to suppose that there exist a tree with $n$ nodes and show that given any tree with $n$ nodes we can have it that $\deg(x_i) = d_i$.

Comment: Your proof is invalid. You have only shown that the sum of the degrees is equal to the sum of $d_i$ for any tree with $n$ nodes. This does not show that each $x_i=d_i$. For example, $1+2+1=2+1+1$, but $1\neq 2$.

Comment: This proof is not valid because you assumed the conclusion (the existence of a tree with the specified degrees of vertices) and proved the hypothesis (the sum of the $d_i$'s is $2n-2$).